# List of role's privileges in Postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, privileges

1. How to get in Postgres list of all privileges granted to a role/user, ex. to the public role?
2. Is that right, that newly created user in Postgres has no privileges except the ones inherited from default public role?

Answer (score 1):

1. In the [`psql` client](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-psql.html) you can list roles and their [*attributes*](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/role-attributes.html) with [`\du+` meta-command](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-psql.html#APP-PSQL-META-COMMAND-DU) which reads [`pg_catalog.pg_roles`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/view-pg-roles.html). To really list all [*privileges*](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-priv.html), you'd have to go through all `information_schema` views with `privileges` in the name, and/or all [lists](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/16/catalog-pg-class.html) of [things](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-oid.html), reading who's the owner of the thing. This system is trying to be very granular, so listing them all is a big operation even on a freshly created database - you'd be listing access to all things and everything that those things are made up of, including the large and complex built-ins.

   `Public` isn't a very good example because it's not really a role - you can `grant` and `revoke` from it but you can't impersonate or connect as just `public`. It's a way for things to cascade and apply to everyone. Since it's not a role, it isn't the default role either.
2. Correct but whatever they can and will `create` will be theirs, so their "number" of privileges grows through expanding ownership, not just `grant`.

Comment: Once I create a new Postgres user I'm able to CREATE TABLE/VIEW, LOGIN TO DATABASE, etc. How to check what kind of operation I'm granted to execute into my schema? For example: How to permit a user to CREATE a TABLE, but disallow him to CREATE SEQUENCE?

Comment: @drk You can revoke `create` entirely but you can't pick and choose what they can or cannot create. You can however restrict [*where*](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-priv.html#DDL-PRIV-CREATE) you allow that, and that dictates *what* this restriction applies to.